# Eclipse: how to silence "Attribute (...) is obsolete..." warnings?

Tags: eclipse

When I pull an Angular project into eclipse it complains about JSON, HTML and other errors and plasters e.g. Angular's entire `node_modules` folder with thousands of warnings like `Attribute (...) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents.` and many others such warnings. ||-(

I am in principle a big fan of keeping warnings enabled, but for *my* code only! I certainly won't start fighting with the Angular tools and start fixing *their* provided and/or generated code.

How can I silence/stop these validations for a specific folder and everything underneath it?

I tried to exclude that folder from the validation settings (in the settings of the HTML and the JSON validator under Windows -> Preferences -> Validation I added a File/Folder Rule underneath "Exclude group") but that doesn't seem to work. These warnings are still there and they re-appear if I re-build.

How does this validator exclude functionality work? Or how else can one exclude certain folders/files from being validated by Eclipse?

This is using Eclipse WTP (Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0) / Build id: 20211202-1639).

[image: Here's an example of what I tried]

Comment: Which tooling/editor of which version? Eclipse WTP or Eclipse Wild Web Developer? Please also provide a sample file to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the exclude group you've set?

Comment: Please consider answering at least the question of nitind, who is the project lead of Eclipse WTP. Calling something rubbish instead of telling how to reproduce your issue is not very professional. Be aware that your question will be read by people wanting to help you rather than knowing what you are fan of.

Comment: I removed the "rubbish" - sorry. It's just that this dialog doesn't work well at all (and that since years). E.g. selecting a folder *always* leaves the result field empty (something that others have reported already). It's also unclear whether the names/paths are supposed to be absolute or relative (and if so, relative to what?). 
I added a screenshot showing misc. entries I had tried.

Comment: @nitind: I added the screenshot as request. Any idea or comment?